# How can I secure installed my windows service exe file from InstallUtil?

Tags: windows, security, service

I have a windows service for a schedule some jobs. It will be sold for a price. 
   I created msi file for setup. After the install, installed folder have an exe file and dll's.(By the way, I am going to install service on customers' computer, so they won't be have msi file) I found out, this installed exe file can be installed with InstallUtil.exe. I have done some research but I cannot found any good explanation. My questions is, how to forbid install with installUtil for installed exe? I am new to this area, any help will be good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: fabulay, the usual approach is to include a license file (with a cryptographic signature) that specifies the MAC address of the onboard ethernet card.  The program can then check the address against the license file and refuse to run if they don't match.  As Gabor's answer points out, this doesn't provide perfect protection, but it is usually enough to discourage casual piracy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to prevent people using your software without paying for it. Unfortunately, it is impossible.

Your code, when it runs on the client, is fully controlled by the client. While you can make things harder, in the end no matter what you do, it will always be possible to run it without your permission. Take any commercial software and then search on torrent for pirate versions. :)

You can go lengths in trying to secure it, and the effort needed from an attacker may become somewhat higher, but it is logically impossible to prevent copying if all of the code is on the client.

What you can actually do is offer your solution as an online service (like a most commonly a webapp these days). That way control remains with you.